# How do I remove a string between two characters in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column containing address information. I want to remove everything between `#` and `,` but also remove the `#` and leave the `,`.

EDIT: I also need to remove the space leading the `#`.

Here is what my column looks like:

```
ADDRESS
123 abc st. #123, city, zipcode
321 def road #321, city, zipcode
```

So my column would look like this:

```
ADDRESS
123 abc st., city, zipcode
321 def road, city, zipcode
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, you also want to remove the space before the `#`:

```
select str, regexp_replace(str, ' #[^,]+,', ',')
from (values ('321 def road #321, city, zipcode')) v(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> ```
> select address, regexp_replace(address,' #[^,]+(?=,)','') from foo;
> ```
>
> ```
> address                          | regexp_replace             
> :------------------------------- | :--------------------------
> 123 abc st. #123, city, zipcode  | 123 abc st., city, zipcode 
> 321 def road #321, city, zipcode | 321 def road, city, zipcode
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4d9eabbfa3dfb2ef3f4d2c272e374ca5&hide=3)*